# Better initial guess can be worse for optimization convergence

Tags: optimization

I have a pretty complicated model with many parameters that I need to solve. Even though the model is complicated, the functional form at each step is not irregular.

I'm seeing some strange behaviors with start values. If I start at standard, random values (all 0s), the solver converges with "Locally optimal solution found", 0 CG iterations, in 673s.

If I start at values that I know are close to the solutions, the solver converges with "Primal feasible solution estimate cannot be improved.", 493 CG iterations, in 1718s.

Note that in both cases, the final values are the same (or very similar).

2 questions:

- What exactly is the number of conjugate gradient iterations, as in, when does the solver need to calculate the conjugate gradient? Here in 1 case I see 0 CG iteration, and in the other case 493 CG iterations. What does that imply? (Note that I do know what CG method is, just not sure why the huge difference here with 0 in one case.)
- What are *all* the possible explanations that 'better' initial values can slow optimization convergence significantly?

Answer (score 5):

From your first question, we learn that you're employing a "smart" solver, i.e. that dynamically adjusts the algorithm to optimally converge. The conjugate gradient method is a good way for "long-range" finding of the optimum, but is slow to converge when you're close to a shallow optimum.

As with all "smart" code, there are situations where the heuristic fails, and you've encountered one. I assume that your optimum is rather shallow, so that the objective function (i.e. the actual criterion you're trying to optimize) varies little if your parameters change a bit. Now there's no way for the solver to know that the parameters are already very close to the optimum. For all it knows it could be very far from the solution in an area where the objective function is pretty flat. After some initial tests, thus defaults to the conjugate gradient method, which is a slow but safe way to approach the optimum. However, since after a lot of searching it doesn't actually get very far, it tells you that if you were lucky, you started close to the optimum, but if you were unlucky, your solution is far, far away from the optimal solution.

If you know that your initial guess will be pretty good, you may thus want to check whether your solver allows specifying which algorithms should/should not be used.

Comment: @user18115: My reference for optimization, [Numerische Mathematik](http://www.amazon.de/Numerische-Mathematik-Hans-Rudolf-Schwarz/dp/3519429608) is in German, which may unfortunately not help you.

Comment: @user18115: I have really no idea how your solver is written. Your guess may very well be correct.

Comment: See @Egon's answer for an explanation of CG.

Comment: @user18115: Regarding why the solver doesn't start one or the other way, as well as why it warns in the end: This depends really on how the solver is written, and should hopefully become apparent from the documentation. It could be that the solver terminated due to maximum number of iterations (though I'd have expected a "round" number), it could be that it has some other heuristics to evaluate the quality of a solution in term of how much the objective function has improved, or how much the parameters improved, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10350/discussion-between-jonas-and-user18115)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the CG method as discussed @Egon.

Answer (score 5):

Conjugate gradient is a [gradient-type](http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~restrepo/475A/Notes/sourcea/node74.html) optimization algorithm (also called "steepest descent"), which can be prone to slow convergence in some cases. Even if you are close to the optimum.

On the [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent), you can find figures to illustrate this behavior, I adapted one of them here:

[image: optimization convergence problems]

What you see are the iso-cost (or iso-objective) lines on the contour plot. Let's imagine we start from point 1, which is quite a good start value. The red lines show the path taken to reach the optimum. We see that it zig-zags towards the optimum, which takes a lot of function evaluations and therefore time.

If we compare that to the performance when we select point A as the starting value, we get faster convergence (or at least, that's what I expect in this case). Let's assume it takes just one iteration in that case.

Now take a look at point 5, it is clearly close to the optimum, but it takes a lot of iterations to get to the optimum. As you are approaching through a narrow valley, the algorithm will jump from one side to the other, making only very small progress towards the optimum on the way. When you approach from the wider side of the valley, you see that the gradient is directed more towards the optimum, which causes a faster convergence.

In your case, it might be the fact that your initial value is somewhat like point 5 above, while the generic starting value is comparable to point A. That's in the assumption that your starting value converges to the true value, which might not be the case. If your starting value is close but there is a peak between it and the global optimum, you will not converge to the right value as is the case in the following figure.

[image]

When knitro changes to either CG or one of their other algorithms, is something that should either be mentioned in the documentation or is only known by the developers of knitro.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the steepest descent method and this behavior you pointed out. Though I was still wondering how I could tell if this is the behavior I'm seeing, and what all the alternative explanations are.

Comment: For the record, Wiki suggests that Conjugate Gradient method is different from Steepest Descent method is different from Line search method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: @user18115: the methods are somewhat different, but their foundations are the same. You follow the gradient of a function, which gives you the way down. However, as explained above, to find the global optimum, you sometimes have to go up as well. However, there is no easy/fast way to know whether you have only found a local optimum. To see whether you are zig-zagging, you need to take a look at the sequence of points you visited in the optimization.

Comment: Yup I'm aware of that. Looking at my iteration results it does seem to be zigzagging. Also, it's interesting that the solver says the number of gradient evaluations is 0 whereas the number of CG iterations is in the hundreds.

Comment: This answer (and especially the figure) is a bit misleading, though---in 2d, CG can go straight to the minimum of any quadratic in just two iterations. The zigzagging behavior only happens when you haven't yet "learned" the shape of the quadratic (`niterations < ndims`). The zigzagging is a much more likely with "plain" gradient descent.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is because the start values are just an approximation of the solution of the problem, since an iterative solution tries to get near by trying to converge into the final values, then, the more near to the answer start values are, the less iterations you need to converge. Also the convergence threshold should count.

This is the classic informed vs non informed problems, if you start with ad-hoc values, the result would be harder to find that if you start with good non ad-hoc values.

Comment: I think you may have misread the question? I'm saying that Closer-to-Solution start values are resulting in many MORE iterations, a lot SLOWER to converge, and WORSE exit flag?

Comment: Yup, sorry, maybe if you try to plot the intermediate values, you can see the dynamics of it and find your answer. Good luck!

Comment: This is a very high dimensional problem. It's not easy to 'plot' it.